# Is a layoff a QLE allowing one to elect different health plan offered by employer?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, cobra

If one is laid off, one is allowed under Cobra to continue group based health insurance thru employer.

Does the layoff count as a QLE allowing one to change health coverage if an employer offers multiple plans?

Comment: The company (usually through it's benefits provider) **always** provides a list of QLEs.  (I work for a big company, though.  If it's a small company, ask HR.)

Answer (score 1):

> You May Change COBRA Plans Only During An Open Enrollment
>
> **The continuation of the same coverage is the same policy that you had the day before the COBRA qualifying event.** When you elect COBRA you will continue the same policy. However, you will be able to change the health plan when your previous employer has open enrollment. You will need to contact the previous employer’s HR department or Benefits Manager to find out the date of open enrollment.

https://www.cobrainsurance.com/kb-questions/changing-cobra-insurance-plans/

However, "loss of coverage" usually is a qualifying event, should you be eligible for health insurance through your partner/family.